# Natural Search in apache Solr(DB and GIS based)

Tags: database, search, solr, gis

dose Apache Solr has a natural  Search from DB (like converting the text Search to a SQL query) and/or

dose it have natural Search based on GIS data.

Example I can ask without have any knowledge about GIS or DB " Give all shops within 500 meters from the centre mall).

Comment: There is nothing built-in to Solr to handle natural language processing (NLP) of a query and transforming it to an internal query, so you'll probably have to write that yourself based on other frameworks based on what kind of information you're trying to let users search (and which terms are relevant).